# GridView scroll to position

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-8.1

In my project I want to preserve scroll position when the user navigates between pages. Currently I want to change position of elements in a GridView. I came up with this test code:

```
void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   ScrollViewer scrollViewer = VisualTreeExtensions.GetVisualChild<ScrollViewer>(gridView);
   scrollViewer.ChangeView(100, null, null);        
}
```

However this code doesn't work, when the ScrollViewer is inside the GridView.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

P.S.
I don't want to use ScrollIntoView method because I want to restore the Scroll position exactly as it was.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using NavigationCacheMode="Enabled"?
If you can't use navigation cache mode, try moving the yourScrollViewer.ChangeView(100,null,null) to yourScrollViewer.OnLoaded.